# What are some words I can say to acknowledge or let the other person know that I am listening?

Tags: word-request

I always use "ok" when I talk to my coworkers and want them to know that I listen and understand what they say. I found that it's redundant and repetitive and want to know alternative words that mean the same thing.

Comment: I just say "yes".

Comment: Since you are just *listening and understanding* whatever is being said and **not** necessarily **agreeing** it, I think the best thing works is 'hhmm' *without* nodding and 'okay'!

Comment: This kind of feedback is known as [backchannels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backchannel_%28linguistics%29). I found a good page about it: http://www.cs.utep.edu/nigel/bc/. On the page, it lists a few common backchannels in American English: *yeah, uh-huh, hm, right, okay*. More interesting part is the [pitch contours of some backchannel examples](http://www.cs.utep.edu/nigel/bc/4cues.png). Also, be careful, as noted on the page: "Obviously one can backchannel when the other person has the floor, but backchanneling just anytime can be rude."

Comment: @MaulikV As someone who *nods* a lot, I'd say that nodding doesn't always mean "agree". Even saying "okay" in this manner (as a backchannel) doesn't always mean "You're correct". Actually, I think it doesn't mean that, most of the time.

Comment: Too much "backchanneling" can be taken as a sign of impatience, so here in our  lab we train the droids to just nod now and then and to use eye contact.

Comment: @DamkerngT. it's a bit of a cultural thing as to what's an agreement and what's a backchannel. Some will take even a nod as a sign of agreement because they'd expect you to interject if you disagree, some will *absolutely* and *yes, of course* their way through your speech before revealing they didn't agree with a word of it.

Answer (score 2):

-Aha (with lips either open or shut!)

-I see

-ok

-following

-listening

-yes/yep

-Oh really?

-Got it

-Okey Dokey

Answer (score 1):

Downvotes have made me think over this question and I found that you want words that show that I am listening and understanding (and NOT agreeing) what you're saying.

There are many ways. A few of them are here-

> I see 
>  yeah 
>  fine  
>  got it 
>  hmm etc.

Comment: My version is even shorter! "Hmmm" ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're speaking face-to-face, a simple attentive look towards the speaker is sufficient-- you don't have to stare, either. Overdoing it with "okays" and "yeahs" is pretty annoying, in my opinion. When I listen to someone speak, I don't say anything unless they're saying something I actually want to agree with or re-affirm. At that point, I usually say one of the following:

> Right. 
>  [That's] correct. 
>  Yes. 
>  Yep. 
>  Definitely. 
>  Absolutely.

The other case I would speak is when I have something to correct them on, or disagree with. I am of the view that your actual response to their statements provides better evidence that you are paying close attention than robotically saying "hmm" or "yes" after every other sentence. Hearing other people do that annoys me because I can no longer tell if they are actually listening or just pretending to listen.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways in responding to the speaker's message, verbally and non-verbally. You could say other words such as "yes", "all right", and "sure" being some of them. Nodding is the commonly used response and one way of responding to someone talk.

Answer (score -1):

Same issue as with Ruchir M's answer - your question was about something else. Due to this, I've updated my answer:

> carry on
>   until now all fine
>   understand
>   oki doki

etc.